# Divs get messed up when i resize the window

Tags: html, css, reactjs

when i resize the window all the elements in the center get crammed and not responsive at all. even in the header the nav items don't resize well either.

my Triangle.js file :

```
 import React from 'react'
 import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
 import './styles/triangle.css'
    
    const Triangle = () => {
      const transition = { duration: 8, ease: "easeInOut"}
      return (
        <>
         <div className='parent' >
           <div className='svgPath'>
             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="900" height="685" viewBox="0 0 1600 800" fill="none">
              <motion.line y1="234.5" x2="1600" y2="234.5" 
              fill='transparent'
              stroke='white'
              strokeWidth={2}
              strokeLinecap
              initial={{ pathLength: 0 }}
              animate={{ pathLength: 1 }}
              transition={transition} />
              <motion.path d="M626.64 7.19272L1059.32 500.806C1063.57 505.654 1060.13 513.25 1053.68 513.25H188.318C181.871 
              513.25 178.428 505.654 182.678 500.806L615.36 7.19271C618.348 3.78441 623.652 3.78441 626.64 7.19272Z" 
              fill='transparent'
              stroke='white'
              strokeWidth={2}
              strokeLinecap
              initial={{ pathLength: 0 }}
              animate={{ pathLength: 1 }}
              transition={transition}/>
            </svg> 
           </div>
            <motion.div 
             className='text1'
            >
                EVERY PRODUCT AND SERVICE CREATED TO BE SOMETHING LARGER THAN ALL OF US.
            </motion.div>
            <div className='text2'>
              We have a very unique model.While we aspire to be achieving players in the markets, 
              we also invite investors and partners to grow our brands together and make a difference as one. 
            </div> 
            <div className='text3'>
              12
            </div>
            <div className='text4'>
              projects and more upcoming.....
            </div>
        </div>
        
      </>
      )
    }
    
    export default Triangle
```

my triangle.css file :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Coda;
    src: url(../../../public/fonts/Coda/Coda-Regular.ttf) format('trueType');
}

.parent{
   padding-left: 200px;
   position: relative;
}

.svgPath{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.text1{
    font-family: Coda;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: xx-small;
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-size: medium;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 225px;
}

.text2{
    font-family: Coda;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: medium;
    width: 460px;
    word-wrap: normal;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 500px;
}

.text3{
    font-family: Monument Extended;
    color: black;
    font-size: 6rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 white,
    2px -2px 0 white,
    -2px 2px 0 white,
    2px 2px 0 white,
    -3px -3px 0 white,
    3px -3px 0 white,
    -3px 3px 0 white,
    3px 3px 0 white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    margin-left: 24%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.text4 {
    font-family: Coda;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: medium;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-top: 10.5%;
    margin-left: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `width:100%` in `.parent` class it'll do the trick

Comment: it is not resizing though.

Comment: go to ```index.html``` and write ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />```

Comment: And if you already have this, you should use @media